# Creating a Llist by merging unequal size of list parellally in Java

Tags: java

I have n number of list of Integer. I need to merge the item of each list parallel i.e. element on index of 0th position of each list should create a new List.

I am able to get it if all the List is in equal in size. However in case of unequal List it is throwing exception/ now working.

Please suggest on this.

```
// here in lst we addedd all list.
    // size of lst = 30
        //sizeListForx= added index position of all list in lst 
    int total = 5;

    for (int k = 0; k < lst.size()/total; k++) {
        currentRecList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int n = 0; n < sizeListForx.size(); n++) {
            currentRecList.add(lst.get(k+n));
        }
        listForAll.add(currentRecList);
    }
```

Here in lst I am adding all list and also keeping there index position

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code (what is your input and what should be your output) examples?

Comment: negative voter please comment.

Comment: @PavelHoral Will add .See in Edit. Thanks

Comment: So you have two `List<String>` instances and want to merge them in `List<List<String>>`? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @PavelHoral I tried it but no luck. Here before this code snippet, I am getting a number of List<Integer> . I am adding all in one list lst and then all keeping all list size in sizeForx list. After that I am iterating through it in the code snippet.

Comment: I have problems understanding your intentions. Please add examples (not code, but data) what is your input and what should be the output.

Comment: Thanks Pavel...thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all your lists to an array, and through that process get the maximum list size. Then you have to do two nested fors. Take a look at this:

```
package tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list0.add(1);
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(2);
        List<Integer>[] listArray = new ArrayList[2];
        listArray[0] = list0;
        listArray[1] = list1;
        int maxListSize = 2;

        List newList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxListSize; i++) {
            List innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = 0; j < listArray.length; j++) {
                if (listArray[j].size() > i) {
                    innerList.add(listArray[j].get(i));
                } else {
                    innerList.add(null);
                }
            }
            newList.add(innerList);
        }
        System.out.println(newList);

    }
}
```